# Can I supply 2 units of peltier module(TEC 12706) connected in series with Lipo (22.2V ) ? will it damage the unit?

Tags: batteries, dc, temperature, lipo

I need to build a portable temperature control cooler box using TEC. I am using 2 units of TEC which has rating of 12V/6A. I understand that parts of the battery may drain very fast but is it possible to connect the supply 22.2V directly two both of the TEC connected in series. From that I will make parallel connection to the cooler fans. As for now I am using a BUCK converter to step down to 12V where it has output limited at 3A(max). Will it damage the units? Tq

Comment: -1 for the sloppy writing.  I quit about halfway thru.  We are all volunteers here, and don't have to put up with that.  Closing as *unclear* since without reading the rest, I don't know what is being asked.

Comment: Im sorry for that .Anyways,I got the answer for the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will it damage the units? Probably not, they have intrinsic resistance which is usually listed on the datasheet. As long as the ohms in the datasheet is above 22.2V/6A = 3.7Ohms the peltiers will limit the current.

If your running the modules in series do not connect loads to the modules, you'll need to run the fans off of a regulator.

If your doing this for any type of product, your going to want more than just an On\Off scheme and some way to limit the current as Peltiers have internal heating and do not operate with the best efficiency when you put the full current/Max power across them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But ,do you think stepping down it to 12V and supply to  TECs that connected in series will better ? What abt batteries , do you think there is any other battery i could use for this project.Moreover , im using PID controlller in this project

Comment: You can get DC to DC converters that are able to have range of voltage outputs (like LT8714). Or you can get DC to DC converters that have a current limit. It depends on what cooling power you need nominally. A good idea would be to plug the PID controller into a benchtop power supply and then figure what your max, min and nominal current and voltage are for all deltaT's across the peltiers and then size your power system around that.

Comment: I think i was wrong about the PID controller .Actually the PID controller I mean is about controlling the speed of the fan accroding the set point choosen ,which i will do that arduino .But im not sure whether this will able the maintain the desired temperature.If possible i wanna reach the desired set point which is in the range of 2-15 C within 15minutes where the capacity of the cooler box is about 15 litres

Comment: This turns into a thermal problem, you need to determine the heat capacity of the system, the heat leakage through the insulation and through the peliters. Then you need to figure out how much heat required (in watts) to reach the desired set point with the rate of cooling. You'll need to drive the peltiers with more than that amount of cooling (in watts). The peltiers have an efficiency curve that is usually found in the datasheets.  You can run peliters with a PID and with a ramp PID, but your PID will not respond faster than the peliters can cool.